# R Installation Error: error in load action .__A__.1 - function not provided by package 'Rcpp'

Tags: r, installation, package, r-package

I am working with the R programming language. I am trying to install the following package (MSGARCH) : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MSGARCH/index.html.

I selected this library from the installation menu:

```
> install.packages("MSGARCH")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/me/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘expm’, ‘fanplot’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/expm_0.999-6.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 239099 bytes (233 KB)
downloaded 233 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/fanplot_4.0.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1971544 bytes (1.9 MB)
downloaded 1.9 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/MSGARCH_2.42.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2824131 bytes (2.7 MB)
downloaded 2.7 MB

package ‘expm’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘fanplot’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘MSGARCH’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpYZtAzv\downloaded_packages
```

This seem to have worked. However, the problem happens when I try to load this package:

```
> library(MSGARCH)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘MSGARCH’ in .doLoadActions(where, attach):
 error in load action .__A__.1 for package MSGARCH: loadModule(module = "MSgarch", what = TRUE, env = ns, loadNow = TRUE): Unable to load module "MSgarch": function 'Rcpp_precious_remove' not provided by package 'Rcpp'
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘MSGARCH’ was built under R version 4.0.5
```

**Question:** Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong? Am I lacking any of the required packages for this package to work? I have posted the session information below.

Thanks

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19043)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] depmixS4_1.5-0      HiddenMarkov_1.8-13 nlme_3.1-149        Rsolnp_1.16         MASS_7.3-53        
 [6] nnet_7.3-14         MSwM_1.5            NHMSAR_1.17         tseries_0.10-48     XML_3.99-0.5       
[11] RCurl_1.98-1.3      wordcloud_2.6       RColorBrewer_1.1-2  SnowballC_0.7.0     tm_0.7-8           
[16] NLP_0.2-1          

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.6      xml2_1.3.2      lattice_0.20-41 quadprog_1.5-8  TTR_0.24.2      tools_4.0.3     xts_0.12.1     
 [8] quantmod_0.4.18 grid_4.0.3      xfun_0.21       ncvreg_3.13.0   tinytex_0.30    lars_1.2        ucminf_1.1-4   
[15] bitops_1.0-6    curl_4.3        slam_0.1-48     compiler_4.0.3  stats4_4.0.3    truncnorm_1.0-8 glasso_1.11    
[22] zoo_1.8-8
```

Comment: Try running update.packages() -- your Rcpp is a release behind, so may other packages too.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to only update the necessary packages? How long do you think this might take?